# What is the variance of a binomial sample probability less a constant

Tags: variance, data-transformation, random-variable, covariance, sample

I don't know the true population parameter "pie" for the binomial distribution. Therefore when I take a sample I estimate it using "p"=x/n where x is number of successes and n is the sample size.

Three questions.

1. In general, my "p" is very small, and so is the true "pie". By small I mean always less than 0.4, but often less than 0.05. Can I use a normal approximation for the distribution of the estimate "p"? Or better yet, should I? This question is the least important though. The below two are more important.
2. I have a second random variable which is equal to Z = "p" - k, where k is a constant. This RV is clearly a transformation of the first RV "p". What is the VARIANCE of my second RV? 
   To give some more context on this question, imagine that I have 4 observations: 4,5,4,5. I also have four observations of: -1,1,-1,1. These could easily represent the difference of the four position observations. Both of these sets of observations have different standard deviations though, and the second set is dependant on the first set (assuming that at any time t you take the observations at time t-1 as given i.e. as constants). If I assumed that the position observations.
   One may have expected the variance of Z = p-k to be equal to Var(Z)=Var(p-k)=Var(p) since k is a constant. However, the above example shows that this isn't true.

Another question may be: what is the covariance of the random variable Z and "p"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What really matters is whether n*$\pi$ is small, with n the sample size and $\pi$ the population proportion. If it is (say smaller than 5), then the outcome $X \sim Binom(n, \pi)$ becomes skewed because of the edge effect: it cannot get smaller than 0. For large values of n*$\pi$, X will be approximately normally distributed, as is $P = \frac{X}{n}$. Remember P is a random variable too. Remember also for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\pi \rightarrow 0$, X is approximately Poisson distributed with $X \sim Poisson(\lambda = n*\pi)$.

2) Subtracting a constant does not change the variance, Var(Z) = Var(P)
3) This equals the variance above, since the constant is of no importance